# Question appears multiple times in a search result with Q : and A :

Tags: discussion, support, search

The Stack Overflow search shows questions twice. See [sample search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=mvc) for example.

Results include *"A: Add Search Engine into MVC Music Store"* and *"Q: Add Search Engine into MVC Music Store"*.

Why is search displaying the question twice, and what does "Q" and "A" mean?

```
Edit:
```

**@Stephen answer :**

The search is returning both a question (Q) and an answer (A) to the question, as both posts match your search criteria.

and **my another question**

If the question have multiple (like 100) answer ,then the answer link(A: Question Link) shown 100 times?

Is it correct functionality ? But i saw only one answer link , not a other answer link .. why ?

Comment: Please don't change your question after it was answered. And please simply use one question mark. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry . Because some peoples does not read comments , so i put that !!!! sorry and thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The search is returning both a question (Q) and an answer (A) to the question, as both posts match your search criteria.

Comment: oh Nice. But if we click a question link, also we can see answer details. why we need that? because lot of data want store database for manage this details !!!

Comment: It's mostly useful if the search terms show up only in the answer and not the question. Or if there are a bunch of answers and you don't want to sift through them to find what you're looking for

Comment: okay . If the question have multiple (like 100) answer ,then the answer link shown 100 times?????

Comment: Only if every answer matches the search terms, I think

Comment: Is it correct functionality ???? But i saw only one answer link , not a other answer link .. why ????

Comment: A big question is "Are the terms in the *question* or even just the *question title* considered search terms for each of that question's *answers*?".  If so...that seems like a problem.