# Why do I sometimes see the same question multiple times when searching in the iOS app?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, ios-app

Sometimes I see exactly the same question come up twice, and an example of this is shown below:

> [image: Screenshot of a duplicate question]

The questions shown might look different, but tapping on them brings me to exactly the same page, and on reporting one of the questions as a duplicate, I get this message:

> [image: Alert box saying: Request failed, a post cannot be a duplicate of itself]

Is this a glitch, or am I missing something? Please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question appears multiple times in a search result with Q : and A :](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191450/question-appears-multiple-times-in-a-search-result-with-q-and-a); see also [Searching gives repetitive Questions and Answers in single result page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207214/398063)

Comment: Look again very closely at your search results for the Q and the A - you found the question and one of its answers. More details at the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "A" in the beginning of the search result means that the result is an *answer*, not a question. The first result in your search is the question itself; the second is an answer to that question. Since they are both physically located on the same page, you're thus redirected to the same page.

What's *supposed* to happen once you tap on the answer link is that it should scroll you to that answer. But I've often seen in the desktop site that if a question has a lot of answers, the page doesn't scroll until it has fully loaded (which can take some time). I'm not sure if that's what's happening in the mobile app (it looks like you're using the iOS app from your screenshots), or if there's some bug that's preventing it from scrolling, but the mobile apps are no longer being actively developed so we can't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks. If my question is a duplicate, should I delete it?

Comment: @DM01131 No, it's helpful as a signpost for those who find this question in search but don't find the target questions. (As a matter of fact, since this answer has been upvoted by others, you can't delete it.)